# Mocked method not returning value from test-local variable

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, kotlin

I have written a test to check if my method for adding and subtracting coins from the userdata preference method is working correctly. I mocked the SharedPreferences class and I am using a local variable `coins` that stores the coin amount.

However the mocked getInt() does not seem to return the correct value of coins:
Running the test *addCoinValid* fails (Expected: 5, Actual: 0). I've made 2 outputs during the test:

variable: 1 - mockedReturn: 0
variable: 5 - mockedReturn: 0

The left number is the value from the variable and the right number is what the mocked *getInt()* returns.

Can anyone tell me what's going on? :O

---

This is my test:

```
class UserDataTest {
    var coins = 0

    val editor = mock<SharedPreferences.Editor>()
    val sharedPrefs = mock<SharedPreferences> {
        on{ getInt("coins", 0) } doReturn coins
        on { edit() } doReturn editor
    }
    val context = mock<Context> {
        on { getSharedPreferences("userdata", 0) } doReturn sharedPrefs
    }
    val userData = UserData(context)

    @Before
    fun initEditorMock() {
        whenever(editor.clear()).thenReturn(editor)
        whenever(editor.putInt(eq("coins"), any<Int>())).thenAnswer{ invocation ->
            this.coins = invocation.getArgument(1)
            return@thenAnswer editor
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun addCoinValid() {
        userData.setCoins(1)
        println("variable: "+coins+" - mockedReturn: "+userData.getCoins())

        userData.addCoins(5)
        println("variable: "+coins+" - mockedReturn: "+userData.getCoins())
        assertEquals(5, userData.getCoins())
    }
    // ...
}
```

And this is the class that is tested:

```
class UserData(context: Context) {
    val settings = context.getSharedPreferences("userdata", 0)

    fun getCoins(): Int {
        return settings.getInt("coins", 0)
    }

    fun setCoins(number: Int) {
        settings.edit().clear().putInt("coins", number).apply()
    }

    fun addCoins(number: Int) {
        if(number < 0) {
            return
        }
        var coins = settings.getInt("coins", 0)
        setCoins(coins+number)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `doReturn coins`, Mockito saves the value that `coins` had at the mock set up time, that is, its initial value `0`, and then returns that saved value ignoring the changes to the actual variable.

To make the mock query the variable each time the function is called, use [`doAnswer { ... }`](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/blob/916f186df947d3b69b14b1f5dc286555dc625549/mockito-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/nhaarman/mockito_kotlin/Mockito.kt#L229):

```
on { getInt("coins", 0) } doAnswer { coins }
```